# Cannot create a runtime on benchmark run

Tags: pallet, frame, benchmarking

Using `polkadot-v0.9.19` branch I've created benchmarks for a pallet, added it into runtime, compiled.
On run of any of created benchmarks getting this error:

> Error:
> Service(Client(RuntimeApiError(Application(VersionInvalid("Instantiation:
> Export ext_crypto_verify_ecdsa_version_1 not found")))))
>
> Cannot create a runtime error=Instantiation("Instantiation:
> Export ext_crypto_verify_ecdsa_version_1 not found")

Need some hint where it may come from.

Edit: When run with sudo - getting this error:

> sudo ./target/debug/polkadex-node benchmark pallet --pallet
> pallet-ocex-lmp --extrinsic "*"
>
> 2022-08-08 17:29:24 [0]  generated 1
> npos voters, 1 from validators and 0 nominators
>
> Error:
> Service(Client(VersionInvalid("Instantiation: Module
> **wbindgen_placeholder** not found"))) 2022-08-08 17:29:25 Cannot create a runtime error=Instantiation("Instantiation: Module
> **wbindgen_placeholder** not found")

Comment: Would you mind sharing the source code? That make it much easier to help, thanks.

Comment: sure, here: https://github.com/Polkadex-Substrate/Polkadex/tree/iv-ocex-benchmarks

Comment: Something seems to messed up with the WASM, this also errors `polkadex-node --dev`. No idea what this means but maybe updating to a newer version will fix it.

Comment: upgrading to `polkadot-v0.9.27` didn't change much. got different error if running with `sudo` thought...

Comment: upgraded code in this branch: https://github.com/Polkadex-Substrate/Polkadex/tree/iv-ocex-benchmarks-27

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi I've trimmed all our pallets, and most (non-essential) FRAME pallets - same error. do you have any other ways to troubleshoot? need to get to the root of this...